# Cómo leer ciertas filas de varios archivos

Tags: r, bucles

Tengo 6 carpetas con 10 archivos cada una. 
Cada archivo tiene una columna con coordenadas. Me gustaría crear un loop o algo similar que me permita leer de todos los archivos de diferentes carpetas solo la fila en la que se encuentra una coordenada concreta. 
Es decir, de cada archivo solo necesito una fila. He conseguido hacerlo para cada carpeta mediante list.files y rbind(lapply), pero me gustaría crear un loop para hacerlo para todas las carpetas. he probado con subset pero no consigo hacerlo en un loop.
Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias!!

Comment: Hi there, please translate your question to Spanish, because you are posting on [es.so]. And when doing that, please ensure you read [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien ya has conseguido leer los archivos de una carpeta, no se que tipo de archivos (csv, xlsx, html,... ) dependiendo de eso tendrás que usar la funcion apropiada para leerlo. 
Si tienes el path de la carpeta padre de las 6 que tienes que leer, esta código que dejo abajo provee un vector con todos los nombres de los archivos que hay en cada carpeta y los nombres del directorio al que pertenece el archivo:

```
# leo los directorios o carpetas, por defecto del directorio de trabajo o
# debo proveer el path al directorio padre de las 6 carpetas 
directorios <- list.dirs(path = getwd(), recursive=F)
# remuevo los directorios ocultos o que empiezan con .

# devuelve un vector con el path y el archivo como elementos
# y el path como nombres
archivos <- function(carp) {
  lista <- sapply(carp, list.files)
  unlist (
    sapply(carp, 
           function(X) {paste(X, lista[[X]], sep="/")}
          )
  )
}

# obtengo los nombres de los archivos
archivos(directorios)
# obtengo los nombres de los directorios
names(archivos(directorios))
```

Luego puedes usar este vector para filtrar los tipos de archivos que interesen o crear una función que, dada el nombre del archivo, lo abra (por ejemplo un .csv) lea lo que hay dentro, seleccione lo que necesites y lo guarde en un okjeto, vector o data.frame.
Una vez que tienes esa función con sapply(lista_de_archivos, función) obtendras una lista que en cada elemento tendrá los datos que necesitabas.

Comment: Gracias! Lo que me has comentado me ha servido mucho. Los archivos los tengo en formato .dat. Los estaba leyendo a través de read.table de esta forma    data2014 <- rbindlist(lapply(file14,read.table, header = FALSE, skip = 15909, nrows = 1)) pero eso solo lo puedo hacer para una carpeta solo, y no estoy usando las coordenadas que es como debería hacerlo. No sé cómo usar lo que me has pasado para leer cada archivo. Soy muy nuevo en R. Gracias por lo que me has pasado.

Comment: Estimado @Jack si la pregunta te sirvió te sugiero que la marques como acepta, esto no sólo aumentará tu puntaje y con ello la posibilidad de obtener más medallas, sino que la comunidad estará más concentrada en resolver otras preguntas que aún han quedado abiertas.